# Child div still seems being dragged despite using stopPropagation on parent's event handler

Tags: javascript, events

In the following example, why `div2` still seems to get dragged despite setting [event capture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_capture) to `true` and using `stopPropagation`? I expect `dragstart` not to get fired on `div2`, and of course it won't, but why I still see the nested element getting dragged?

```js
const div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
div1.addEventListener("dragstart", div1EventHandler, true);
const div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
div2.addEventListener("dragstart", div2EventHandler, true);

function div1EventHandler(event) {
  console.log("taget: " + event.target.id);
  console.log("currentTarget: " + event.currentTarget.id);
  event.stopPropagation();
}
function div2EventHandler(event) {
    console.log("taget: " + event.target.id);
    console.log("currentTarget: " + event.currentTarget.id);
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: coral;
}

#div2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" draggable="true">
  <div id="div2" draggable="true">
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't see my question as a duplicate of mentioned question. As I mentioned `stopPropagation` works and the event does not get fired on `div2` but I still see `div2` being dragged.

Comment: Why on the child? Event capture is true which means the event fires first on the least nested element, and then on successively more nested elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `preventDefault()` to cancel the default browser action. The default action happens whether you stop propagation or not. It's related to the browser context, not your DOM.

```js
const div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
div1.addEventListener("dragstart", div1EventHandler, true);
const div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
div2.addEventListener("dragstart", div2EventHandler, true);

function div1EventHandler(event) {
  console.log("taget: " + event.target.id);
  console.log("currentTarget: " + event.currentTarget.id);
  event.preventDefault();
}
function div2EventHandler(event) {
    console.log("taget: " + event.target.id);
    console.log("currentTarget: " + event.currentTarget.id);
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: coral;
}

#div2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" draggable="true">
  <div id="div2" draggable="true">
  </div>
</div>
```